# Why the total of time dilation from different frames of reference is equal to 2 when velocity is under 1000km/s

Tags: special-relativity

Recently, i have researched on time dilation and found that time dilation(observed from rest) in a clock moving with body (b) with a three digit velocity(say 580) and time dilation(observed from a moving body) in clock at rest with another body (a) when added with each other, the grand total is always exactly 2. i want to know the reason behind this peculiar fact that addition of time dilation with a velocity of three digit only is 2. because when i calculate the time dilation with a velocity of 1000, its total is not exactly 2. thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are going to have to explain your calculation in more detail; as written, your question makes no sense. What are your units of time dilation? Could it be that you are really seeing a rounding error on your calculation (calculator?), where $$\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}\approx 1$$ when $v$ is sufficiently small (and when you add the two numbers together, you get 1+1=2)?

Comment: i mean to say that i have calculated the dilated time in clocks(one at rest and one is moving) from both bodies's point of view. the rest time is 1 second in both equations, the velocity can be any three digit number. when you put the values in both time dilation equations(one for calculating dilated time in clock moving observed from rest and one for calculating dilated time in rest clock observed by moving body) and add the answers you get, you will always get the answer of 2. try it and let me know.

Comment: Simple first order expansion of the square root tells us that the number you calculate should be "not quite 2" for any non-zero value of $v$. But since the difference from 1 goes as $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$, when $v\ll c$ the difference may "look like" zero (less than 1 part in 10$^{10}$ which will look like 0 on a 10 digit calculator).

Comment: for an example, let us take the velocity as 100km/s and rest time as 1 sec. lorentz factor is 0.000000011111. the time dilation in moving clock observed from rest is 0.99999994444 and dilated time observed from moving body is1.00000005556. the addition of both values is

Comment: for an example, let us take the velocity as 100km/s and rest time as 1 sec. lorentz factor is 0.000000011111. the time dilation in moving clock observed from rest is 0.99999994444 and dilated time observed from moving body is1.00000005556. the addition of both values is 0.99999994444+1.00000005556=2

Comment: Hi PiyushKapoor, please *edit* your question instead of leaving clarifications in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to this equation:

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-2\approx 0$$

To prove this is not "exactly" zero for small values of $v$, we need to rearrange things a bit. Let's put $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$. First multiply by $\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$, then perform a [Taylor expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+sqrt(1-x)):

$$\begin{align}(1-\beta) + 1 - 2\sqrt{1-\beta^2} &=\\
 2-\beta^2-2\left(1-\frac12 \beta^2 -\frac18 \beta^4 - ...\right) &\approx\\
\frac{\beta^4}{8}\end{align}$$

When v = 100 km/s, 10$^5$ m/s, we find from direct calculation that the difference between the "exact" result and 2 is only $1.5\cdot 10^{-15}$, which is less than the resolution of a typical double precision calculation. Which is why you think the difference is "exactly" zero.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion floris. you really helped me out.